# iTunes 10 on Windows - how do I change the color scheme, theme, or skin?

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, itunes

I have installed iTunes 10.1 on Windows 7 64 bit, and like many others, I am not happy with the color scheme where the icons on the left vertical navigation are all grey.

What is the easiest, safest way to change this to simply be color like it was under iTunes 9?  I am not looking for a fancy skin, and I am not sure I can trust pre-built iTunes.exe files that some on the internet are distributing, and may not work with 64-bit.

Many solutions exist for Mac to edit the package and change a resource file, but this is not an option for Windows users

[image]

Comment: As a matter of reference, iTunes on 64-bit is the same as on 32-bit Windows. It's just the installer that is 64-bit. So you should be fine looking at other 32-bit hacks for this problem.